# Evaluate the given limit in $C_r=\{re^{i\theta}:0\le \theta \le \pi\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let , $C_r=\{re^{i\theta}:0\le \theta \le \pi\}$ denotes the semicircle traversed clockwise. Show that $$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz=-\pi i$$

I can not use the Jordan's theorem, as the limit $r\to 0$. I tried through putting $z=re^{i\theta}$ , but it does not help..How I find the limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz&=-\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{e^{ire^{i\phi}}} {re^{i\phi}(r^2e^{i2\phi}+1)}ire^{i\phi}d\phi\\\\
&=-\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ie^{ire^{i\phi}}} {r^2e^{i2\phi}+1}d\phi \tag 1\\\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi} \lim_{r\to 0}\left(\frac{ie^{ire^{i\phi}}} {r^2e^{i2\phi}+1}\right)d\phi\tag 2\\\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi}\,i\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\pi i
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ the interchange of the limit and the integral is justified by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).  Here,

$$\left|\frac{ie^{ire^{i\phi}}} {r^2e^{i2\phi}+1}\right| \le \frac{1}{|1-r|^2}$$

and obviously the constant $\frac{1}{|1-r|^2}$, $r\ne 1$, is integrable on the interval of interest.

Comment: I think you dropped an $=$ and an $i$.

Comment: You need $r^2e^{2i\phi}$ downstairs

Comment: Why would I delete the comment?

Comment: In terms of clutter, note that we have 6 comments on what "clockwise" means. Really I'm in favor of leaving these conversations as they are. It shows students that typos (and even big mistakes) can be made by highly qualified people, like yourself. I note you deleted your comment above, so now mine is a conversation with the air. PS: It might be good to add a remark about passing the limit throught the integral sign; you're using uniform convergence? Might be good to say so.

Answer (score 5):

It is not difficult to show that if $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ \lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)\,dz}{z^2+1} = 0 $$
since both $|f(z)|$ and $\left|\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right|$ are bounded in a neighbourhood of the origin, while the length of the integration path is $\pi r\to 0$. $\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z}$ is an entire function, hence:
$$ \lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}\,dz = \lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z(z^2+1)}=\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z}\tag{1} $$
where the last equality follows from the same argument, since $$\int_{C_r}\left(\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}-\frac{1}{z}\right)\,dz =-\int_{C_r}\frac{z\,dz}{z^2+1}$$ is the integral of a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin.

The last integral in $(1)$ can be computed in a explicit way by substituting $z=r e^{i\theta}$:
$$ \int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z} = -ri\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{r} = -\pi i.\tag{2}$$

Comment: This is really, really neat. Nice observation!

Comment: @jackd'aurizio In the spirit of this development, how did we arrive at $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z(z^2+1)}=\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z}$  While it is true, do we not need to show this?  Else, we might as well bring the limit inside immediately and bypass a step or two.

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is indeed the same argument, since $$\int_{C_r}\left(\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}-\frac{1}{z}\right)\,dz =\int_{C_r}\frac{z\,dz}{z^2+1}$$ is the integral of a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: @Dr.MV: anyway, I agree it is worth mentioning. Thanks for your reviews.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, given a function $f$ with a simple pole at $z= \alpha$, we have:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\Delta_{\epsilon,\theta}}{f(z)dz}=i\theta\cdot \text{Res}(f,\alpha). 
$$
Where $\Delta_{\epsilon,\theta}$ is an arch (with positive direction) about $\alpha$ with radius $\epsilon$, over an angle of size $\theta$.

In your case, set $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}$, $\,\,\alpha=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, and you'll get the result by reversing the direction (multiplying by $-1$).

(Note that in your case: $\text{Res}(f,\alpha) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}zf(z)=1$)

Now, lets prove the claim:

Since $\alpha$ is a simple pole, $f$ can be written as follows:
$$
f(z) = \frac{\text{Res}(f,\alpha)}{z-\alpha} + g(z)
$$
Where $g$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\alpha$.
Let $M$ be an upper bound of $|g|$ in that neighbourhood.
Thus, for small enough $\epsilon$:
$$
\left|\int_{\Delta_{\epsilon,\theta}}{g(z)dz}\right|\le M\cdot\epsilon\theta\tag{1}
$$
Also,
$$
\int_{\Delta_{\epsilon,\theta}}{\frac{dz}{z-\alpha}}=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0+\theta}{\frac{\epsilon i e^{it}}{\epsilon e^{it}}dt}=i\theta\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, and setting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ we get the result.